# Filter only Exchange service ips

Tags: json, powershell, filter

Running into an issue where I want to filter and only use the IPs related specifically to Exchange online, and nothing else.

I can easily grab all the IPs for all services, but the goal is to only grab the IPs for the Exchange online service. I've tried variants of select-object and where-object but not successful

Here's what I have working...I've left the attempts at code out because they never returned any value

```
$o365Uri = "https://endpoints.office.com/endpoints/worldwide?clientrequestid=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7"
$iplist = Invoke-RestMethod $o365Uri
$iplist
```

and if i just want all the ips...

```
$iplist.ips
```

I only want the $iplist.ips for a specific where the `serviceArea` = `Exchange` though. URLs could also be used instead of ips. Either works.

Comment: you can filter the IP's by class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. This returns only the IPs for the exchange service

```
# Call the O365 API to get the IP addresses
$uri = "https://endpoints.office.com/endpoints/worldwide?clientrequestid=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7"
$call = Invoke-RestMethod $uri

$exchange = $call | where {$_.serviceArea -eq "Exchange"}
$exchangeUrls = $exchange.urls
```